# How to properly change back umlauts?

Tags: bash, sed

I am working on an old shop database with book titles. All the german umlauts ä, ö, ü and ß have been replaced by ae, oe, ue and ss. I would like to change them back. However, just replacing them does not work. For example the fictional book title "iblue's neue Abenteuer mit Uebersetzungsproblemen" (iblue's new adventures with translation issues) would be converted to "iblü's neü Abenteür mit Übersetzungsproblemen". Only the last word is correct. In the first 3, ue occur naturally and should be kept.

Someone must have had that problem before me. Is there away to solve this? I would prefer bash and sed, but if it has been solved in any other language I would be happy to see any solution.

Comment: In order to do such a thing, you need knowledge of the German language. You can't expect basic bash or shell commands having that knowledge, so you'll need to find a German-handling library for this.

Comment: That's a very useful idea. Since I can execute other binaries in bash, I would take your suggestion on which one to use.

Comment: What happens if the database contains the word "lassen"? You would incorrectly change it to "laßen". Similarily, your approach would change the word "Bauer" to "Baür". Also what happens if the title to convert, is a book from Switzerland? In Swiss, the ß is never used.

Comment: There is no safe approach to your problem. In particular if there are titles of novels, the author could deliberately decide to use "ae" instead of t "ä" in the title. Once you have translated the umlauts away, they are lost. You need to keep somewhere the book representation in its original form. The same problem appears when you translate a book title to a different language and at one time need to recreate the original form.

Comment: If the shop database also stores ISBN then you might be able to look up the official titles in a public database. Or feed the mangled title to a search engine like google books, isbnsearch, etc.